# Push notification on count.ly

Tags: android, countly-analytics

Below is the code snippet which is demo application listed in countly documentation for sending push notifications to user in android & we have community edition of countly , issue is users are not even getting registered in countly.

[Demo provided by countly](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-android)

After adding necessary credentials in above demo app none of those is actually registering my device in countly , is countly accurate to show live users ? or am i missing anything wrong in below code ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver;

    /**
     * You should use try.count.ly instead of YOUR_SERVER for the line below if you are using Countly trial service
     */
    final String COUNTLY_SERVER_URL = "http://xxxx";
    final String COUNTLY_APP_KEY = "xxxx";
     final String COUNTLY_MESSAGING_PROJECT_ID = "xxxx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Context appC = getApplicationContext();
        Countly.onCreate(this);
        Countly.sharedInstance().setLoggingEnabled(true);
        Countly.sharedInstance().setPushIntentAddMetadata(true);
        Countly.sharedInstance().enableCrashReporting();
        Countly.sharedInstance().setViewTracking(true);
        Countly.sharedInstance().setAutoTrackingUseShortName(true);
        Countly.sharedInstance().setRequiresConsent(false);
        Countly.sharedInstance().setConsent(new String[]{Countly.CountlyFeatureNames.sessions}, true);
        Countly.sharedInstance().init(appC, COUNTLY_SERVER_URL, COUNTLY_APP_KEY)
                .initMessaging(this, MainActivity.class, COUNTLY_MESSAGING_PROJECT_ID, Countly.CountlyMessagingMode.PRODUCTION);

        Countly.sharedInstance().recordEvent("test", 1);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Countly.sharedInstance().recordEvent("test2", 1, 2);
            }
        }, 5000);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Countly.sharedInstance().recordEvent("test3");
            }
        }, 10000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Countly.sharedInstance().onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Countly.sharedInstance().onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Register for broadcast action if you need to be notified when Countly message received
        messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Message message = intent.getParcelableExtra(CountlyMessaging.BROADCAST_RECEIVER_ACTION_MESSAGE);
                Log.i("CountlyActivity", "Got a message with data: " + message.getData());

                //Badge related things
                Bundle data = message.getData();
                String badgeString = data.getString("badge");
                try {
                    if (badgeString != null) {
                        int badgeCount = Integer.parseInt(badgeString);

                        boolean succeeded = ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getApplicationContext(), badgeCount);
                        if (!succeeded) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to put badge", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to parse given badge number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(CountlyMessaging.getBroadcastAction(getApplicationContext()));
        registerReceiver(messageReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't see your user on Countly dashboard, it's one of the following:

- Wrong `COUNTLY_APP_KEY`;
- Wrong `COUNTLY_SERVER_URL`;
- Some connectivity issue - your device cannot access that server.

You've enabled logging by `Countly.sharedInstance().setLoggingEnabled(true)`, so your Logcat should have some errors which would tell you which one of those is about your case.

Also you use `sdk-messaging` dependency instead of `sdk-messaging-fcm`. First one uses GCM, which is deprecated in favor of FCM, that is Firebase. We have [a detailed guide for that](https://resources.count.ly/docs/countly-sdk-for-android#section-setting-up-push-notifications).